# Trouble with WPF ScrollViewer resize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have an issue with a ScrollViewer in WPF.

When a Window is sized down to the point where the ScrollViewer should start taking over, the window doesn't resize the containing grid and bottom of the scroll bar just goes out of view.

I have tried binding the height of it to the height of the containing grid, but with no luck.

Here is my xaml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Width="Auto" Height ="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StackPanel Height="134" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label x:Name="ProjectNumberLabel" Content="ProjectNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45.5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" FontSize="32" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>

        <Label x:Name="ProjectNameLabel" Content="ProjectName" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White" Width="auto"/>

        <Label x:Name="SetLabel" Content="Set Id" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Width="Auto" Height="42" Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" />

    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,140,0,0" Width="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Height="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualHeight  }">
        <StackPanel Name="ContainingPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="300"/>

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <CheckBox x:Name="ComplexDataCheckBox" Content="Show All Data" Click="ComplexDataCheckBox_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="1.751,0.547" Margin="0,4,0,0" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="105" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                    </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="SpecimenGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource styleselector}"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Seeing how you're placing your components, the outer grid is useless, a `DockPanel` would have beeen sufficient. To place other controls in a Grid you have to define `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions`. As for the `ScrollViewer` don't define it's height, but define `VerticalAlignement` to stretch. The scrollbar will appear once the content wont' fit anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if ScrollViewer has a Height equal to Grid height *and* not zero-vertical margin, it goes out Grid bounds.

it is better to put StackPanel and ScrollViewer in two separate Grid Rows:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <!--Content-->
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Margin="0"
                  CanContentScroll="True" >
        <!--Content-->
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested and it seams like the ScrollViewer height wants to still match whatever it's content is and not the container Grid Row that it is in.

Comment: Never mind this whole things was contained inside another StackPanel, Ichanged that to a Grid as well and the issue is now fixed.  Thank you very much for your help